# Interpretation of interaction term with a logged dependent variable

Tags: interaction, interpretation

I would like to know how to interpret the coefficient on an interaction term as a percentage change when the dependent variable is logged. I provide an example below using the `mtcars` data set in `R` where `am` is binary and `wt` is continuous.

$\ln(mpg)= \beta_0 + \beta_1\cdot wt + \beta_2\cdot am + \beta_3\cdot wt\cdot am$

In this case, I would interpret the main effect on `am` to mean that when `wt=0`, `mpg` increases by 47.7% when `am` moves from 0 to 1, where `47.7 = exp(0.38981)-1)*100`.

I would like to know if coefficient on the interaction can also be interpreted as a percentage change. For example, exponentiating the coefficient for the interaction yields `(exp(-0.15391)-1)*100 = -14.3%`. My interpretation is that for a one unit increase in `wt`, `mpg` decreases by 14.3% more for `am=1` versus `am=0`.

I've already plotted the interaction effects, but because the y-scale is in logged mpg the substantive interpretation isn't obvious even though the plot illustrates the interaction quite clearly.

```
data(mtcars)

summary(mtcars[,c("mpg", "wt", "am")])

m1 <- lm(log(mpg) ~ wt + am + wt*am, data=mtcars)

summary(m1)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.72680    0.15145  24.607  < 2e-16 ***
wt          -0.24148    0.03940  -6.129 1.29e-06 ***
am           0.38981    0.21383   1.823   0.0790 .  
wt:am       -0.15391    0.07245  -2.124   0.0426 *
```